# Hanging Excel after running a macro copied to another file

Tags: vba, excel, copy, freeze

Good afternoon. My question is connected with VBA macros in Excel. My macro works without complaints every time it's outside the file from which data is moved to an another file. But since I inserted it into the Excel file from which it gets some data as well as I made a command button (in the first file) that runs my macro, it works properly but finally... The Workbook into which it "translates" data simply hangs and I cannot do anything except from closing Excel with Task Manager. Do you have any idea what is the reason for such an odd action?
This is my code:
    Sub Inc2(i As Currency, j As Currency)
        i = i + j
    End Sub
    Sub Przypisz_date(komorka As Range, data As Variant)
        If komorka.Value = "" Then
            data = ""
        Else: data = CStr(komorka.Value)
        End If
    End Sub

```
Sub Dodaj_poz(ByRef it As Integer, ByRef kom As Range, ByRef rodzaj_calk As Variant, ByRef rodzaj As Variant, _
              ByRef nr_rodzaj As Integer, Optional ByRef czy_data As Boolean = False)

    If it = 1 And czy_data = True Then
        rodzaj(1) = CStr(Format(rodzaj(1), "dd-mm-yyyy"))
    End If
If czy_data = False Then
    If IsError(Application.Match(kom.Value, rodzaj, 0)) And _
        kom.Value <> 0 And it > 1 Then
                    nr_rodzaj = nr_rodzaj + 1
                    rodzaj(nr_rodzaj) = kom.Value
                    rodzaj_calk = rodzaj_calk & "/" & rodzaj(nr_rodzaj)
    End If
End If
If czy_data = True Then
     If IsError(Application.Match(CStr(Format(kom.Value, "dd-mm-yyyy")), rodzaj, 0)) And _
        kom.Value <> "" And kom.Value <> 0 And it > 1 Then
                    If it = 2 Then
                    rodzaj_calk = rodzaj(1)
                    End If
                    nr_rodzaj = nr_rodzaj + 1
                    rodzaj(nr_rodzaj) = kom.Value
                    rodzaj_calk = Mid(CStr(Format(rodzaj(nr_rodzaj), "dd-mm-yyyy")), 1, 5) & "/" & rodzaj_calk
    End If
End If
End Sub
Sub Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(ByRef rodzaj_calk As Variant, ByRef rodzaj As Variant, ByRef nr_rodzaj As Integer, _
                              kom As Range, Optional czy_data As Boolean = False)

rodzaj(nr_rodzaj) = kom.Value

Select Case czy_data
    Case True
        rodzaj_calk = CStr(Format(rodzaj(nr_rodzaj), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
    Case False
        rodzaj_calk = rodzaj(nr_rodzaj)
End Select

End Sub

Sub Przenies_dane_do_APlatnosci() 'Main Submodule

Dim sciezka_pocz_zest As String
Dim zest As String
Dim sciezka_zest As String
Dim wb_zest As Workbook
Dim ws_zest As Worksheet

Dim nr_bud As String

Set wb_zest = ActiveWorkbook
sciezka_pocz_zest = wb_zest.Path
zest = wb_zest.Name

sciezka_zest = sciezka_pocz_zest & "\" & zest

Set ws_zest = wb_zest.Worksheets("Zestawienie")

nr_bud = Left(Right(wb_zest.Name, Len(wb_zest.Name) - 19), Len(Right(wb_zest.Name, Len(wb_zest.Name) - 19)) - (Len(wb_zest.Name) - InStr(1, wb_zest.Name, ".") + 1))

Const sciezka_pocz_apla = "(a path)"
Const apla = "(filename).xls"
Dim sciezka_apla As String
Dim wb_apla As Workbook
Dim ws_apla As Worksheet

sciezka_apla = sciezka_pocz_apla + apla

Workbooks.Open Filename:=sciezka_apla

Set wb_apla = Workbooks(apla)
Set ws_apla = wb_apla.Worksheets(nr_bud)

Dim numer_it As Integer
Dim i_nr_obw As Integer

Dim nr_faktury_hp_tb As Date
Dim data_faktury_hp_tb As Date
Dim data_sprzedazy_wykonania As Date
Dim status_vat As String

Dim nr_zlec_zd As String
Dim nr_zlec_inw As String
Dim data_wplywu As Variant
Dim rejon_cz_zamaw As String
Dim miejsce As String
Dim rejon_drog As String
Dim strefa_wschod_zachod As String
    Dim obwod(1 To 100) As String
    Dim nr_obw As Integer
    Dim obwod_calk As String
    Dim droga(1 To 100) As String
    Dim nr_dro As Integer
    Dim droga_calk As String
    Dim miejscowosc_lokalizacja(1 To 100) As String
    Dim nr_m_lok As Integer
    Dim m_lok_calk As String
Dim nazwa_zlecenia As String

    Dim wskazany_termin_realizacji(1 To 20) As Variant
    Dim nr_treal As Integer
    Dim treal_calk As String

    Dim data_wykon(1 To 200) As Variant
    Dim nr_dwyko As Integer
    Dim dwyko_calk As String

    Dim data_zgl_do_odb(1 To 200) As Variant
    Dim nr_d_zo As Integer
    Dim d_zo_calk As String

    Dim okr_do_fakt(1 To 20) As Variant
    Dim nr_okr_do_fakt As Integer
    Dim okr_do_fakt_calk As String

    Dim firma_realiz(1 To 20) As String
    Dim nr_f_realiz As Integer
    Dim f_realiz_calk As String

    Dim zlec_wart_netto_calk As Currency

Dim real_wart_netto_tb_hp As Currency
Dim real_wart_brutto_tb_hp As Currency

    Dim data_fakt_tb_hp(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_tb_hp As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_tb_hp_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_tb_hp(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_tb_hp As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_tb_hp_calk As String

    Dim data_fakt_partner_1(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_partner_1 As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_partner_1_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_partner_1(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_partner_1 As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_partner_1_calk As String

    Dim data_fakt_partner_2(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_partner_2 As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_partner_2_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_partner_2(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_partner_2 As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_partner_2_calk As String

    Dim data_fakt_partner_3(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_partner_3 As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_partner_3_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_partner_3(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_partner_3 As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_partner_3_calk As String

    Dim data_fakt_partner_4(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_partner_4 As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_partner_4_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_partner_4(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_partner_4 As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_partner_4_calk As String

        Dim real_wart_netto_PODW As Currency

    Dim data_fakt_PODW(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_PODW As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_PODW_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_PODW(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_PODW As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_PODW_calk As String

        Dim real_wart_netto_PODW2 As Currency

    Dim data_fakt_PODW2(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_PODW2 As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_PODW2_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_PODW2(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_PODW2 As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_PODW2_calk As String

        Dim real_wart_netto_PODW3 As Currency

    Dim data_fakt_PODW3(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_PODW3 As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_PODW3_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_PODW3(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_PODW3 As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_PODW3_calk As String

        Dim real_wart_netto_PODW4 As Currency

    Dim data_fakt_PODW4(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_PODW4 As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_PODW4_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_PODW4(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_PODW4 As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_PODW4_calk As String

        Dim wart_netto_jPODW As Currency

    Dim data_fakt_jPODW(1 To 10) As Variant
    Dim nr_data_fakt_jPODW As Integer
    Dim data_fakt_jPODW_calk As String

    Dim nr_fakt_jPODW(1 To 10) As String
    Dim nr_nr_fakt_jPODW As Integer
    Dim nr_fakt_jPODW_calk As String

Const kol_status_vat_apla = (column number)
Const kol_stat_zlec_apla = ...
Const kol_nr_zlec_zd_apla = ...
Const kol_nr_zlec_inw_apla = ...
Const kol_data_wplywu_apla = ...

'And so on - declarations of constants

Dim koniec_zest_wl As Integer
Dim koniec_zest_zm As Integer
Dim koniec_apla As Integer
Dim koniec_apla_ost As Integer

Dim aplat_empty As Boolean
Dim zest_empty As Boolean

Dim firma As String
Dim firma_opcj As String

Dim pocz_firma_opcj
Dim licznik_firm
Dim suma As Currency

Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim i_pocz_zlec As Integer
Dim i_konc_zlec As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Integer

Dim akt_wiersz As Integer

Dim czy_dodawac_wiersz As Boolean

    i = 0
    k = 0
    suma = 0
    czy_dodawac_wiersz = False
    licznik_firm = 1

    aplat_empty = False
    zest_empty = False

    koniec_zest_wl = ws_zest.Cells(ws_zest.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    koniec_zest_zm = koniec_zest_wl
    koniec_apla = ws_apla.Cells(ws_apla.Rows.Count, kol_nr_zlec_zd_apla).End(xlUp).Row


ws_apla.Range("S:U").NumberFormat = "General"

If koniec_apla = 10 Then

    aplat_empty = True

End If

If koniec_zest_wl = 4 Then

    zest_empty = True

End If


If aplat_empty = True And zest_empty = True Then
    MsgBox Prompt:="Nie można uaktualnić danych w pliku Apłatności, ponieważ w zestawieniu zleceń nie ma żadnych numerów zleceń!", Title:="Error!"
    Exit Sub
End If

If Not ws_apla.Cells(koniec_apla, kol_nr_zlec_zd_apla) = _
            ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm, kol_nr_zlec_zd_zest) Then

    If aplat_empty = True Then
        koniec_zest_zm = 4
    Else
        Do

            koniec_zest_zm = koniec_zest_zm - 1

        Loop Until ws_apla.Cells(koniec_apla, kol_nr_zlec_zd_apla) = _
        ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm, kol_nr_zlec_zd_zest)
    End If

    Do

                nr_obw = 1
                nr_dro = 1
                nr_m_lok = 1
                nr_treal = 1
                nr_dwyko = 1
                nr_d_zo = 1
                nr_okr_do_fakt = 1
                nr_f_realiz = 1
                'and so on

                obwod_calk = ""
                droga_calk = ""
                m_lok_calk = ""
                treal_calk = ""
                dwyko_calk = ""
                d_zo_calk = ""
                okr_do_fakt_calk = ""
                f_realiz_calk = ""
                'and so on

                i = i + 1
                numer_it = 0
                akt_wiersz = koniec_zest_zm + i

                real_wart_netto_tb_hp = 0
                real_wart_brutto_tb_hp = 0
                real_wart_netto_PODW = 0
                real_wart_netto_PODW2 = 0
                real_wart_netto_PODW3 = 0
                real_wart_netto_PODW4 = 0
                wart_netto_jPODW = 0

     status_vat = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_status_vat_zest).Value
     nr_zlec_zd = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_nr_zlec_zd_zest).Value
     nr_zlec_inw = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_nr_zlec_inw_zest).Value
                Call Przypisz_date(ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_data_wplywu_zest), data_wplywu)
     rejon_cz_zamaw = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_rejon_cz_zamaw_zest).Value
                    obwod(nr_obw) = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_obwod_zest).Value
                    obwod_calk = obwod(nr_obw)
                    droga(nr_dro) = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_droga_zest).Value
                    droga_calk = droga(nr_dro)
                    miejscowosc_lokalizacja(nr_m_lok) = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_miejscowosc_lokalizacja_zest).Value
                    m_lok_calk = miejscowosc_lokalizacja(nr_m_lok)
     nazwa_zlecenia = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_nazwa_zlecenia_zest).Value
                    wskazany_termin_realizacji(nr_treal) = CStr(Format(ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_wskazany_termin_realizacji_zest).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
                    treal_calk = CStr(Format(wskazany_termin_realizacji(nr_treal), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
                    data_wykon(nr_dwyko) = CStr(Format(ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_data_wykon_zest).Value, "yyyy-mm-dd"))
                    dwyko_calk = CStr(Format(data_wykon(nr_dwyko), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
                    data_zgl_do_odb(nr_d_zo) = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_data_zgl_do_odb_zest).Value
                    d_zo_calk = CStr(Format(data_zgl_do_odb(nr_d_zo), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
                    okr_do_fakt(nr_okr_do_fakt) = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_okr_do_fakt_zest).Value
                    okr_do_fakt_calk = CStr(Format(okr_do_fakt(nr_okr_do_fakt), "yyyy-mm-dd"))
                    firma_realiz(nr_f_realiz) = ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_firma_realiz_zest).Value
                    f_realiz_calk = firma_realiz(nr_f_realiz)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_tb_hp_calk, data_fakt_tb_hp, nr_data_fakt_tb_hp, _
                                                    ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_data_fakt_tb_hp_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_tb_hp_calk, nr_fakt_tb_hp, nr_nr_fakt_tb_hp, _
                                                    ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_nr_fakt_tb_hp_zest))


                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_partner_1_calk, data_fakt_partner_1, _
                                                   nr_data_fakt_partner_1, ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, _
                                                   kol_data_fakt_partner_1_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_partner_1_calk, nr_fakt_partner_1, _
                                                   nr_nr_fakt_partner_1, ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, _
                                                   kol_nr_fakt_partner_1_zest))
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_partner_2_calk, data_fakt_partner_2, _
                                                   nr_data_fakt_partner_2, ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, _
                                                   kol_data_fakt_partner_2_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_partner_2_calk, nr_fakt_partner_2, _
                                                   nr_nr_fakt_partner_2, ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, _
                                                   kol_nr_fakt_partner_2_zest))
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_partner_3_calk, data_fakt_partner_3, _
                                                   nr_data_fakt_partner_3, ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, _
                                                   kol_data_fakt_partner_3_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_partner_3_calk, nr_fakt_partner_3, _
                                                   nr_nr_fakt_partner_3, ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, _
                                                   kol_nr_fakt_partner_3_zest))
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_partner_4_calk, data_fakt_partner_4, _
                                                   nr_data_fakt_partner_4, ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, _
                                                   kol_data_fakt_partner_4_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_partner_4_calk, nr_fakt_partner_4, _
                                                   nr_nr_fakt_partner_4, ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, _
                                                   kol_nr_fakt_partner_4_zest))

                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_PODW_calk, data_fakt_PODW, nr_data_fakt_PODW, _
                                                   ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_data_fakt_PODW_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_PODW_calk, nr_fakt_PODW, nr_nr_fakt_PODW, _
                                                   ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_nr_fakt_PODW_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_PODW2_calk, data_fakt_PODW2, nr_data_fakt_PODW2, _
                                                   ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_data_fakt_PODW2_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_PODW2_calk, nr_fakt_PODW2, nr_nr_fakt_PODW2, _
                                                   ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_nr_fakt_PODW2_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_PODW3_calk, data_fakt_PODW3, nr_data_fakt_PODW3, _
                                                   ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_data_fakt_PODW3_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_PODW3_calk, nr_fakt_PODW3, nr_nr_fakt_PODW3, _
                                                   ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_nr_fakt_PODW3_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(data_fakt_PODW4_calk, data_fakt_PODW4, nr_data_fakt_PODW4, _
                                                   ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_data_fakt_PODW4_zest), True)
                    Call Ustaw_wart_pocz_zmiennych(nr_fakt_PODW4_calk, nr_fakt_PODW4, nr_nr_fakt_PODW4, _
                                                   ws_zest.Cells(akt_wiersz, kol_nr_fakt_PODW4_Zest), True)
                    'and so on

                k = k + 1
                i_pocz_zlec = koniec_zest_zm + i
                i = i - 1

                Do

                    i = i + 1
                    numer_it = numer_it + 1

                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_obwod_zest), obwod_calk, obwod, nr_obw)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_droga_zest), droga_calk, droga, nr_dro)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_miejscowosc_lokalizacja_zest), m_lok_calk, miejscowosc_lokalizacja, nr_m_lok)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_wskazany_termin_realizacji_zest), treal_calk, wskazany_termin_realizacji, nr_treal, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_wykon_zest), dwyko_calk, data_wykon, nr_dwyko, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_zgl_do_odb_zest), d_zo_calk, data_zgl_do_odb, nr_d_zo, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_okr_do_fakt_zest), okr_do_fakt_calk, okr_do_fakt, nr_okr_do_fakt, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_firma_realiz_zest), f_realiz_calk, firma_realiz, nr_f_realiz)

                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_tb_hp_zest), data_fakt_tb_hp_calk, data_fakt_tb_hp, nr_data_fakt_tb_hp, True)

                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_tb_hp_zest), nr_fakt_tb_hp_calk, nr_fakt_tb_hp, nr_nr_fakt_tb_hp)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_partner_1_zest), data_fakt_partner_1_calk, data_fakt_partner_1, nr_data_fakt_partner_1, True)

                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_partner_1_zest), nr_fakt_partner_1_calk, nr_fakt_partner_1, nr_nr_fakt_partner_1)

                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_partner_2_zest), data_fakt_partner_2_calk, data_fakt_partner_2, nr_data_fakt_partner_2, True)

                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_partner_2_zest), nr_fakt_partner_2_calk, nr_fakt_partner_2, nr_nr_fakt_partner_2)

                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_partner_3_zest), data_fakt_partner_3_calk, data_fakt_partner_3, nr_data_fakt_partner_3, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_partner_3_zest), nr_fakt_partner_3_calk, nr_fakt_partner_3, nr_nr_fakt_partner_3)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_partner_4_zest), data_fakt_partner_4_calk, data_fakt_partner_4, nr_data_fakt_partner_4, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_partner_4_zest), nr_fakt_partner_4_calk, nr_fakt_partner_4, nr_nr_fakt_partner_4)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_PODW_zest), data_fakt_PODW_calk, data_fakt_PODW, nr_data_fakt_PODW, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_PODW_zest), nr_fakt_PODW_calk, nr_fakt_PODW, nr_nr_fakt_PODW)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_PODW2_zest), data_fakt_PODW2_calk, data_fakt_PODW2, nr_data_fakt_PODW2, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_PODW2_zest), nr_fakt_PODW2_calk, nr_fakt_PODW2, nr_nr_fakt_PODW2)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_PODW3_zest), data_fakt_PODW3_calk, data_fakt_PODW3, nr_data_fakt_PODW3, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_PODW3_zest), nr_fakt_PODW3_calk, nr_fakt_PODW3, nr_nr_fakt_PODW3)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_PODW4_zest), data_fakt_PODW4_calk, data_fakt_PODW4, nr_data_fakt_PODW4, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_PODW4_Zest), nr_fakt_PODW4_calk, nr_fakt_PODW4, nr_nr_fakt_PODW4)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_data_fakt_jPODW_zest), data_fakt_jPODW_calk, data_fakt_jPODW, nr_data_fakt_jPODW, True)
                Call Dodaj_poz(numer_it, ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_nr_fakt_jPODW_zest), nr_fakt_jPODW_calk, nr_fakt_jPODW, nr_nr_fakt_jPODW)

                Call Inc2(real_wart_netto_tb_hp, CCur(ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_real_wart_netto_tb_hp_zest).Value))
                Call Inc2(real_wart_brutto_tb_hp, CCur(ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_real_wart_brutto_tb_hp_zest).Value))
                Call Inc2(real_wart_netto_PODW, CCur(ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_real_wart_netto_PODW_zest).Value))
                Call Inc2(real_wart_netto_PODW2, CCur(ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_real_wart_netto_PODW2_zest).Value))
                Call Inc2(real_wart_netto_PODW3, CCur(ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_real_wart_netto_PODW3_zest).Value))
                Call Inc2(real_wart_netto_PODW4, CCur(ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_real_wart_netto_PODW4_zest).Value))
                Call Inc2(wart_netto_jPODW, CCur(ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + i, kol_wart_netto_jPODW_zest).Value))

                Loop Until Not ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_zm + (i + 1), kol_nr_zlec_zd_zest) = _
                                    nr_zlec_zd

                i_konc_zlec = koniec_zest_zm + i

With ws_apla
    With .Cells((koniec_apla + k), 8)
         .NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
         If .Formula = "" Then
            .Formula = "=IF(I" & CStr(.Row) & ">0,I" & CStr(.Row) & "+30,M" & CStr(.Row) & "+30)"
         End If
    End With
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_status_vat_apla).Value = status_vat
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_stat_zlec_apla).Value = "NW"
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_zlec_zd_apla).Value = nr_zlec_zd
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_zlec_inw_apla).Value = nr_zlec_inw
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_wplywu_apla).Value = data_wplywu
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_rejon_cz_zamaw_apla).Value = rejon_cz_zamaw
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_obwod_apla).Value = obwod_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_droga_apla).Value = droga_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_miejscowosc_lokalizacja_apla).Value = m_lok_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nazwa_zlecenia_apla).Value = nazwa_zlecenia
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_wskazany_termin_realizacji_apla).Value = treal_calk
            If data_wykon(1) <> 0 Then
                .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_wykon_apla).Value = dwyko_calk
            Else:
            .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_wykon_apla).NumberFormat = "General"
                    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_wykon_apla).Value = ""
            End If
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_zgl_do_odb_apla).Value = d_zo_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_okr_do_fakt_apla).Value = okr_do_fakt_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_firma_realiz_apla).Value = f_realiz_calk

            .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_real_wart_netto_tb_hp_apla).Value = real_wart_netto_tb_hp
            .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_real_wart_brutto_tb_hp_apla).Value = real_wart_brutto_tb_hp

        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_tb_hp_apla).Value = data_fakt_tb_hp_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_tb_hp_apla).Value = nr_fakt_tb_hp_calk

        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_partner_1_apla).Value = data_fakt_partner_1_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_partner_1_apla).Value = nr_fakt_partner_1_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_partner_2_apla).Value = data_fakt_partner_2_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_partner_2_apla).Value = nr_fakt_partner_2_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_partner_3_apla).Value = data_fakt_partner_3_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_partner_3_apla).Value = nr_fakt_partner_3_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_partner_4_apla).Value = data_fakt_partner_4_calk
        .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_partner_4_apla).Value = nr_fakt_partner_4_calk

    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_PODW_apla).Value = data_fakt_PODW_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_PODW_apla).Value = nr_fakt_PODW_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_PODW2_apla).Value = data_fakt_PODW2_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_PODW2_apla).Value = nr_fakt_PODW2_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_PODW3_apla).Value = data_fakt_PODW3_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_PODW3_apla).Value = nr_fakt_PODW3_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_PODW4_apla).Value = data_fakt_PODW4_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_PODW4_apla).Value = nr_fakt_PODW4_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_data_fakt_jPODW_apla).Value = data_fakt_jPODW_calk
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_nr_fakt_jPODW_apla).Value = nr_fakt_jPODW_calk


    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_real_wart_netto_PODW_apla).Value = real_wart_netto_PODW
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_real_wart_netto_PODW2_apla).Value = real_wart_netto_PODW2
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_real_wart_netto_PODW3_apla).Value = real_wart_netto_PODW3
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_real_wart_netto_PODW4_apla).Value = real_wart_netto_PODW4
    .Cells((koniec_apla + k), kol_wart_netto_jPODW_apla).Value = wart_netto_jPODW

End With

Loop Until ws_apla.Cells(koniec_apla + k, kol_nr_zlec_zd_apla) = _
            ws_zest.Cells(koniec_zest_wl, kol_nr_zlec_zd_zest)

koniec_apla_ost = ws_apla.Cells(Rows.Count, 19).End(xlUp).Row

For l = 0 To (koniec_apla_ost - koniec_apla - 1)

ws_apla.Rows(koniec_apla + l).Copy
ws_apla.Rows(koniec_apla + l + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats

Next l

End If

Workbooks(wb_zest.Name).Close SaveChanges:=False
Workbooks(wb_apla.Name).Close SaveChanges:=True
MsgBox ("APłatności zostały pomyślnie uaktualnione!")

End Sub
```

Comment: The problem is in the 14th line of code.

Comment: I agree but the code has more than 900 lines... I'd like to find out what could be the problem. In my opinion, code is correct because it is typed in such way that starting from another file doesn't matter. Code is the same, macro starts from another file that original, macro works absolutely well almost to the end and then - Excel completely hangs and does not do the last two lines of my macro (closing file and MsgBox). I think the lag is not directly connected with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had another look through you code and noticed that you define wb_zest as ActiveWorkbook and i am guessing this is where the above code resides.

You are then trying to close wb_zest, the problem here is the code can't close the workbook that the current sub is running in.

As you stated the code used to reside somewhere else and is now in wb_zest so you would no longer need to close wb_zest.

Try removing this line altogether and see how it runs.

Hope this helps

Comment: Maybe that is the key to the mystery. Thanks, I'll try.

Comment: Great! Your idea has solved the problem. Thank you very much! Thread can be closed.

Comment: Do you need to vote for an answer or select one as correct? I’m not sure I’m new to this forum.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, without code it's hard to know what the problem is. If you are using a macro to fire a second macro in a different workbook, that is probably your problem. It is better to run the entire procedure from one workbook.

Comment: I don't use macro to run a second macro. There is only one submodule which uses other subs within the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn’t:

Workbooks(wb_zest.Name).Close SaveChanges:=False

Be:

wb_zest.Close False

Didn’t understand why you are calling it’s name when it is already defined as a workbook.

Comment: Yes, of course, thank you. This is total nonsense :)

Comment: Have you tried placing the code in a standard module and using a form button instead of a command button?